# Tracing back a Foreign Key error in a failing rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

whew! After doing some migrations both on Table Name and Column Name, one of my rspec tests is failing and I have trouble tracing it back to what has caused it. So here is my rspc test that is failing because of this line in it:

```
it { should belong_to(:key_performance_indicators) }
```

by generating this error:

> 1) KeyPerformanceInterval
>        Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:key_performance_indicators) }
>          Expected KeyPerformanceInterval to have a belongs_to association called key_performance_indicators (KeyPerformanceInterval
>   does not have a key_performance_indicators_id foreign key.)

So how should I trace it back? here is my class that it is talking about in the test:

```
class KeyPerformanceInterval < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :key_performance_indicators

end
```

Please let me know if we need more source code to look at and I will update the question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed,
in the shoulda matcher I should removed the character "s" from the name of the table, so it should be:

```
it { should belong_to(:key_performance_indicator) }
```